# Making Combination and Checking each feasible combination

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column (A) having values

```
| 3, 4, 5|
|2, 4, 5|
|4, 5|
|2, 3|
|5|
|4|
|3|
```

and all other possible 3,2 and 1 point combinations from set {2,3,4,5}. I want all possible combination between these elements such that there is no repetition of numbers in the sets, i.e `|3, 4, 5|` can only combine with `|2|` or `|3, 4|` can only combine with `|2, 5|` or `|2|` and `|5|`

```
Dim lRowCount As Long
Dim temp As String, s As String
Dim arrLength As Long
Dim hasElement As Boolean
Dim plans() As String, currentPlan() As String
Dim locationCount As Long
Dim currentRoutes As String
Dim line As Long

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
lRowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
locationCount = -1
line = 2

Debug.Print ("*********")

For K = 2 To lRowCount - 1
    currentRoutes = ""
    For i = K To lRowCount
        s = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
        Do
            temp = s
            s = Replace(s, " ", "")
        Loop Until temp = s
        currentPlan = Split(Trim(s), ",")
        arrLength = UBound(currentPlan) - LBound(currentPlan) + 1
        hasElement = False

        If Len(Join(plans)) > 0 Then
            For j = 0 To arrLength - 1
                pos = Application.Match(currentPlan(j), plans, False)

                If Not IsError(pos) Then
                    hasElement = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        End If
        If Not hasElement Then
            currentRoutes = currentRoutes & (Join(currentPlan, ",")) & " "
            If Len(Join(plans)) > 0 Then
                plans = Split(Join(plans, ",") & "," & Join(currentPlan, ","), ",")
            Else
                plans = currentPlan
            End If
        End If
    Next i
If locationCount < 0 Then
    locationCount = UBound(plans) - LBound(plans) + 1
End If

If (UBound(plans) - LBound(plans) + 1) < locationCount Then
    Debug.Print ("Invalid selection")
Else
    Debug.Print (Trim(currentRoutes))
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(line, 11) = currentRoutes
    line = line + 1
End If

Erase plans
Debug.Print ("*********")
Next K
```

The current problem is that if a combination `|3,4|` is selected it then checks only for one next possible combination, i.e. it takes `|3,4|` & `|2,5|` but doesn't check `|2|` & `|5|`. Please help me to address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

here is a short code to generate all combinations from a set

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As String
    a = "2345"
    combine a, 3 'list all possible combinations of 3 characters from string a
End Sub
Sub combine(a As String, numberofvalues As Integer, Optional level As Long = 1, Optional solution As String = "", Optional firsti As Long = 1, Optional combinationcount As Long = 0)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = firsti To Len(a)
        solution = solution & Mid(a, i, 1)
        combinationcount = combinationcount + 1
        Sheets("sheet1").Cells(combinationcount, 1) = solution
        If level < numberofvalues Then
            combine a, numberofvalues, level + 1, solution, i + 1, combinationcount
        End If
        solution = Left(solution, Len(solution) - 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I need to select the possible combinations from the given set of values

Comment: @Shyam, This code gives you in sheet1 all the possible combinations from the set of values given in a. after that you can select the combination you want and reformat it the way you need it.

Comment: @h2s04 these combinations are already filtered out combinations from the set. The only criteria i want is to not select repeating elements and check for all from the upcoming combinations.

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't understand your request.

I hope my understanding is correct now.

```
Dim lRowCount As Long
Dim temp As String, s As String
Dim arrLength As Long
Dim hasElement As Boolean
Dim plans() As String, currentPlan() As String
Dim locationCount As Long
Dim currentRoutes As String
Dim line As Long

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
lRowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
locationCount = -1
line = 2

Debug.Print ("*********")

For K = 1 To lRowCount - 1
    currentRoutes = ""
    For i = K To lRowCount
        s = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
        Do
            temp = s
            s = Replace(s, " ", "")
            s = Replace(s, "|", "")
            s = Replace(s, ",", "")
        Loop Until temp = s
        If i = K Then
            currentRoutes = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
            elements = s
        Else
            hasElement = False
            For j = 1 To Len(s)
                If InStr(elements, Mid(s, j, 1)) > 0 Then hasElement = True: Exit For
            Next j
            If Not hasElement Then
                elements = elements & s
                currentRoutes = currentRoutes & " " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print (Trim(currentRoutes))
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(line, 11) = currentRoutes
    line = line + 1

    Erase plans
    Debug.Print ("*********")
Next K
```

Comment: Hopefully I have tried to ask this question in a more logical way in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076690/make-feasible-combination-among-the-given-column-elements Can you please have a look on to it